# how to send property value as a message sent by multiple object?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, add-on, scene

i was working on a game and i need to send multiple property values from different objects through different scenes using message body set to "property"

[image]

any ideas ?

Comment: I think you may be at the end of what the game logic nodes can do, and you need to start working with the API.

Comment: i searched for some answers and i found this [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86823/assign-property-value-with-message-body) tried the SumBodiesToValues script but it only accepts the top sensor brick connected to the assign property actuator

Answer (score 1):

As ZargulTheWizard mentioned, the only way to receive the body text/values at run-time is with Python API. However, you could use a different setup, that being to send a simple **"buy.100"** message as you showed above, than, on the object(s) that are meant to be receiving the messages vie message sensors, have them use a property actuator with type **"copy"** to copy the **"value"** property to and fro the sending/receiving objects. You'll also need to have a game-property with the same type (e.g boolean, integer, float) on the receiving object(s).